# How to read json data of a bad request (status code 400) using Alamofire

Tags: json, alamofire

I was calling a Rest API locally from terminal. This was like below:

```
http -v -f --timeout=60 GET 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/public/users/signin?email=myemail@email.com&password=mypassword'
```

It is returning following output:

```
GET /api/v1/public/users/signin?email=myemail@email.com&password=mypassword HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.8.0



HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 28 Mar 2016 16:59:08 GMT
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sun, 27-    Mar-2016 16:59:13 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "debugMessage": "Submitted credentials for token     [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - najmul@qianalysis.com, rememberMe=true] did not match the expected credentials.Submitted credentials for token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - najmul@qianalysis.com, rememberMe=true] did not match the expected credentials.: The subject was expected to be true, but was false",
    "errorCode": "INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS",
    "logId": "50a695c1a81e0542",
    "stackTrace": "org.niopack.r.....
}
```

Now I want to read this JSON data using Alamofire. I tried with responseJSON serialiser with following way:

```
Alamofire.request(method, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL, headers: cookieHeader)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON {

        alamofireResponse in

        let jsonData = alamofireResponse.result.value
    }
```

But this I am getting jsonData as nil. What you will do if you were are here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me removing the `validate()` allowed me to see the reason the request was failing. For some reason when `validate` fails, the data of the response is not parsed.

Comment: this is still true as of 4/2021